# How to multiprocessingly save figure to file in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing

I am trying to save many matplotlib figures to png disk files, since the savefig() is slow, i try to improve the speed by using multiprocess module.

Here is my code: (my environment is Windows XP + python_2.6.1 + Matplotlib_1.2.0 + multiprocessing_0.70a1)

```
import multiprocessing
from figure_creation_mudule import fig_list

def savefig_worker(fig, img_type, folder_path):
    file_name = fig.FM_figname 
    fig.savefig(folder_path+"\\"+file_name+"."+img_type, format=img_type)
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    for fig in fig_list:
        pool.apply_async(savefig_worker, [fig, 'png', 'D:\\img_folder'])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

And `fig_list` is a list imported from other module and contains matplotlib figure object.

```
>>> fig_list
[<matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x0AAA1670>, <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x0AD2B210>, <matplotlib.figure.Figure object at 0x0B277FD0>]
```

When I run the code, it meets problems:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\lib\threading.py", line 522, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Python\lib\threading.py", line 477, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 225, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

What does it mean ? How to fix it ?

Comment: I don't have any experience with this, but from the looks of it, `pool.apply_async()` will internally pickle the task you are sending it so that a separate process/thread can unpickle it and use it(In python the `pickle` module provides a way to serialize and de-serialize arbitrary objects). Looks like matplotlib figures can't be pickled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this and indeed, `Pool.apply_async()` will pickle objects behind the scenes. To confirm this, try this in the REPL:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool
>>> def test(obj):
...   print obj
... 
>>> class A():
...   def __getstate__(self):
...     print "pickling"
...     return {}
... 
>>> pool = Pool()
>>> pool.apply_async(test, [A()])
<multiprocessing.pool.ApplyResult object at 0x10bbe82d0>
pickling

>>> <__main__.A instance at 0x10bbe83b0>
```

To avoid this, you need to use something other than `multiprocessing.Pool` to do the job. `multiprocessing.Process` can work. However, you should take care not to spawn too many processes or you will slow things down instead of speeding things up.

Edit: If you're intent on using `multiprocessing.Pool` [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865430/multiprocessing-pool-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-thread-lock-attribu) should be of help