# multiprocessing multithreading manager python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to get multiprocessing and multi-threading to work together nicely. I have the following code which I have derived from the multiprocessing documentation found at https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager
from threading import Thread


def foo():
  print ("hello world")

def simple_process(threads_manager):
  """Simple process that starts Threads
  """
  threads = []
  for i in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=foo, args=())
    t.start()
    t.join()
    threads.append(t)
  threads_manager['threads'] = threads

manager = Manager()
threads_manager = manager.dict()
p = Process(target=simple_process, args=(threads_manager, ), kwargs={})
p.start()
p.join()
threads = threads_manager.get('threads')

print (threads)
```

but when I run the code I get the following error.

```
hello world
Process Process-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "multiprocessing_multithreading.py", line 17, in simple_process
    threads_manager['threads'] = threads
  File "<string>", line 2, in __setitem__
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 758, in _callmethod
    conn.send((self._id, methodname, args, kwds))
TypeError: can't pickle thread.lock objects
None
```

I'm trying to get the threads spawned by the simple_process function as a threads list.
Can someone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiprocessing.Pool - PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865430/multiprocessing-pool-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-thread-lock-attribu)

Comment: passing the `threads_manager` as arg to the the Process p will not work, since it will be copyed to the new process. As far as I know

Comment: Why processes *and* threads? It seems overly complicated.

Comment: Since error is resolved, I'd like to point out that calling `t.join()` right after `t.start()` is blocking. You wouldn't start new thread until last created thread stopped working. Which is directly countering usage of threads.

Comment: @TomaszPlaskota what are you proposing? I have removed the `t.join()` but still the same error... :(

Comment: @RolandSmith This model is proposed by my boss plus it looks logical to me.

Comment: @Haroon Because of the peculiarities of CPython, the use cases of `multiprocessing` and `threading` do not overlap. CPU-bound work in CPython is not suited for threads because of the Global Interpreter Lock ("GIL") which enforces that only one thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode. I/O-bound work might or might not benefit from either, depending on the details.

Comment: Hm..., If I put aside the multi-threading part what other options do I have. We are planning to build a server monitoring system and we want to limit one client to one process. what should we use achieve parallelism that can be tracked?