# PicklingError: When object is passed as a parameter using partial

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing a program in python that uses multiprocessing.
The below code throws an exception when "param_data" is an object of any class. If it's any other data type its working fine.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(processes=8)
from functools import partial
func = partial(test_function, param_data)
data = {}
range = {"5": {"34": "343"}, "2": {"34": "343"}}
r = pool.map(func, range)
```

The error is -

```
 PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: You need to provide more code (your sample doesn't work at all because half of the things you mention are never defined), but this is probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7865430/1256452

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiprocessing.Pool - PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865430/multiprocessing-pool-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-thread-lock-attribu)