# Can't pickle _thread.RLock objects - I cant see the problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pickle

I know every pickle problem has its own solution. I am getting the general error.

```
can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

This is my model. Can you see a problem with it?

```
def myModel():
    no_Of_Filters=60
    size_of_Filter=(5,5) # THIS IS THE KERNEL THAT MOVE AROUND THE IMAGE TO GET THE FEATURES.
                         # THIS WOULD REMOVE 2 PIXELS FROM EACH BORDER WHEN USING 32 32 IMAGE
    size_of_Filter2=(3,3)
    size_of_pool=(2,2)  # SCALE DOWN ALL FEATURE MAP TO GERNALIZE MORE, TO REDUCE OVERFITTING
    no_Of_Nodes = 500   # NO. OF NODES IN HIDDEN LAYERS
    model= Sequential()
    model.add((Conv2D(no_Of_Filters,size_of_Filter,input_shape=(imageDimesions[0],imageDimesions[1],1),activation='relu')))  # ADDING MORE CONVOLUTION LAYERS = LESS FEATURES BUT CAN CAUSE ACCURACY TO INCREASE
    model.add((Conv2D(no_Of_Filters, size_of_Filter, activation='relu')))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=size_of_pool)) # DOES NOT EFFECT THE DEPTH/NO OF FILTERS
 
    model.add((Conv2D(no_Of_Filters//2, size_of_Filter2,activation='relu')))
    model.add((Conv2D(no_Of_Filters // 2, size_of_Filter2, activation='relu')))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=size_of_pool))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
 
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(no_Of_Nodes,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5)) # INPUTS NODES TO DROP WITH EACH UPDATE 1 ALL 0 NONE
    model.add(Dense(noOfClasses,activation='softmax')) # OUTPUT LAYER
    # COMPILE MODEL
    model.compile(Adam(lr=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
 
 
############################### TRAIN
model = myModel()
print(model.summary())
history=model.fit_generator(dataGen.flow(X_train,y_train,batch_size=batch_size_val),steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch_val,epochs=epochs_val,validation_data=(X_validation,y_validation),shuffle=1)
```

Link to all of the code.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VlZVGPmd6AEMMvZ-98cTmrvYtDgun8HI?usp=sharing

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57233539/typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-rlock-objects?r=SearchResults&s=1|244.5971)?

Comment: Every pickle problem is different.

Can you link me to an article that solves this problem?

Comment: The link is in my comment.

Comment: I have a flatten and dense layer.