# TypeErr: cant pickle '_thread.RLock' object - Objective: save model in .joblib format to reuse after so .joblib needed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pickle, joblib

The objective is to save my model as a `.joblib` file. Using `joblib.dump` method I get the error found in the end of this question. I have indeed found some solutions to save my model in other formats, as in `.pb` with `model.save`, but I need a `.joblib` file to be able to reuse it later in a code expecting such format.

I've checked different similar issues, but none have the same root cause, some are about serialization problem due to Lambda expressions - not my case apparently - namely [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44144584/typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-lock-objects) as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47066635/checkpointing-keras-model-typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-lock-objects/47068604#47068604).

My code for saving currently is:

```py
        RANDOM_SEED = 314 
        TEST_PCT = 0.3

        df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/terzan matthieu/Desktop/STAGE FDR/creditcard.csv")

        df_norm = df.copy()
        df_norm['Time'] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df_norm['Time'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
        df_norm['Amount'] = StandardScaler().fit_transform(df_norm['Amount'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

        train_x, test_x = train_test_split(df_norm, test_size=TEST_PCT, random_state=RANDOM_SEED)

        test_y = test_x['Class']  

        test_x = test_x.drop(['Class'], axis=1)  

        train_x = train_x[train_x.Class == 0] 
        train_x = train_x.drop(['Class'], axis=1)  

        train_x = train_x.values                    
        test_x = test_x.values                      

        nb_epoch = 50
        batch_size = 128
        input_dim = train_x.shape[1] #nb de colonnes, 30
        encoding_dim = 18
        hidden_dim1 = 10 #int(encoding_dim / 
        hidden_dim2 = 6
        learning_rate = 1e-7

        input_layer = Input(shape=(input_dim, ))

        encoder = Dense(encoding_dim, activation="tanh", 
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(learning_rate))(input_layer)
        encoder = Dense(hidden_dim1, activation="elu")(encoder)
        encoder = Dense(hidden_dim2, activation="tanh")(encoder)
        decoder = Dense(hidden_dim2, activation='elu')(encoder)
        decoder = Dense(hidden_dim1, activation='tanh')(decoder)
        decoder = Dense(input_dim, activation='elu')(decoder)

        autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=decoder)


        autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam',
                    metrics=['accuracy'],
                    loss='mean_squared_error')


        cp = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="model.h5",
                     save_best_only=True,
                     verbose=0)

        tb = TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs',
                 histogram_freq=0,
                 write_graph=True,
                 write_images=True)

        history = autoencoder.fit(x=train_x, y=train_x,
                          epochs=nb_epoch,
                          batch_size=batch_size,
                          shuffle=True,
                          validation_data=(test_x, test_x),
                          verbose=1,
                          callbacks=[cp, tb]).history

        autoencoder = load_model('model.h5')
        joblib.dump(autoencoder,'firstautoencoder')
```

And the error stacktrace:

```
      File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\Desktop\Algos_DL\Algo4\Autoencoder1FINAL.py", line 191, in <module>
    joblib.dump(autoencoder,'firstautoencoder')

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 480, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 485, in dump
    self.save(obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 601, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 715, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 558, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 969, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 995, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 558, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 929, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 953, in _batch_appends
    save(x)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 601, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 715, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 558, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 969, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 995, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 558, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 929, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 956, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 601, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 715, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 558, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 969, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 995, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 601, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 715, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 558, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 969, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 995, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 601, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 715, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 558, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 969, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 995, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 601, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 715, in save_reduce
    save(state)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 558, in save
    f(self, obj)  # Call unbound method with explicit self

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 969, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.items())

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 995, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 282, in save
    return Pickler.save(self, obj)

  File "C:\Users\terzan matthieu\anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 576, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)

TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

Why exactly is this happening?
thank you in advance for any help :)

Comment: Is your question resolved now ? Else, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64023727/14290681) especially hotfix, may helps you.