# Pickle class instance from inside a method

Tags: python, oop, machine-learning, save, pickle

I have ModelCollections class which is supposed to take class instances from a Model class and store these instances inside a dictionary:

```
class ModelCollection():

def __init__(self, collection_id):
    
    self.collection_id = collection_id
    self.classification_library = {}
    self.pred_library = {}


def save_model(self, model_instance):
    
    if model_instance.y_type == 'class':
        self.classification_library[model_instance.model_id] = model_instance
    if model_instance.y_type == 'pred':
        self.pred_library[model_instance.model_id] = model_instance
```

I now want to implement a commit_to_disk method as part of this ModelCollection class which should basically pickle 'self':

```
def commit_to_disk(self):

        with open('04 Models/04.3 Model Collections/collection_'+self.collection_id+'.pkl', 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(self, f)
```

This, however, returns the following error:

```
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Is it not possible to save 'self' like this or am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: `self` is just a variable. There is nothing special about it with regards to pickling. Not all objects are pickleable. For example, a `_thread.RLock` object. Somehow, when you try to pickle your object, it would include a `_thread.RLock` object, hence the error.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How could I work around this error?

Comment: Don't try to pickle an object with an `_thread.RLock` object? I'm not sure what else to tell you, you haven't provided a [mcve] so I can only guess at what  would be causing it. I suspect whatever model instances you are trying to pickle are the offending thing, but again, I can only guess.

Comment: Voting to close, because it seems to need details (where is the `_thread.RLock` appearing?).  But maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/q/44144584/10495893