# Workflow for multiple queries from pyspark to mysql

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have to query a mysql database from a pyspark app using a huge txt file (millions of rows) to build the queries.

The txt files has the following structure:

```
ID | time | list of words
```

And query should be something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.time = time  AND table.word IN list of words
```

And then I should do some further operations on the results.

By reading the [SPARK SQL documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#untyped-dataset-operations-aka-dataframe-operations) I have found that I can connect to the mysql database, load it into a Dataframe and then filter it. Something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').master('local[*]').getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").option(
    "url","jdbc:mysql://localhost/<my_database>").option(
    "driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option(
    "dbtable","<my_table>").option(
    "user","<my_username>").option(
    "password","<my_password>").load()
df.filter((df['time'] == row[1]) & (df['word'].isin(row[2])))
```

Here I am using just one `row` of the txt file and everything works fine. My problem now is how to iterate this procedure for all the rows.

I have tried the following, but I get a [pickling error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44144584/typeerror-cant-pickle-thread-lock-objects) (question shows the same error but from a different procedure):

```py
request_data = sc.textFile(<my_huge_text_file>).map(
    # get_rows_in_correct_format reads rows in the correct format
    lambda x: get_rows_in_correct_format(x)).map(
    lambda x: df.filter(df['time'] == x[1]).filter(df['word'].isin(x[2]))
)
```

Is there something I should try other than iterating over the txt rows one by one?