# Create object while still running code

Tags: python, multithreading, object, subprocess

So I have some python code that creates objects like so:

```
paramToPassa = 'test'
paramToPassb = 'test2'
paramToPassc = 'test3'
paramToPassd = 'test4'
#... so on

objectToCreate = continuouslyRunningObject(paramToPassa, paramToPassb)
print('test')
objectToCreate2 = continouslyRunningObject(paramToPassc, paramToPassd)
```

The object instantiates with a `while True:` loop so it runs indefinitely after it's created (it does terminate eventually, but the time varies). The problem is I want to create `objectToCreate2` simultaneously and have it also running at the same time as `objectToCreate`. Normally, the `print` statement is only called along with `objectToCreate2` after the `objectToCreate` is finished running. Is there any way to do this easily or will I have to look into multi-threading/something of that nature? Thanks!

EDIT: Tried using Multiprocessing.Process to create objects like so...

```
a = Process(target=continouslyRunningObject, args=(paramToPassa, paramToPassb))
a.start()
```

but now I get the error `'TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects'`. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want two codes to run simultaneously, you need to use threads.

Comment: Looked into it more. Any idea what the error I got is? Thanks! EDIT: Should mention I tried googling the error (as you do) but all I got were SO pages about Multiprocessing.Pool and Multiprocessing.Queue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865430/multiprocessing-pool-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-thread-lock-attribu

Comment: I assume `Process` is using them internally.