# Implementing Multiproccessing on multi return functions

Tags: python-3.x

I am fairly new to python (and stack overflow!), and i have never used Multiprocessing. I currently have a function that returns two values. The values are appended to different lists. The function has multiple required arguments, one of which comes from a for loop, see example code below.

The code works, however the function is slow. I would like to implement MultiProcessing for this task, however i cant seem to get it working based on a pool, due to the fact that i am getting multiple return values.

```
for x in list1:
    (a, b) = function(x, y, z)
    if a is not None:
        list2.append(a)
    if b is not None:
        list3.append(b)
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Can you post the MP code that causes your code to fail/produce undesirable results? Just a note, no function really has multiple return values; your function returns a *single* object (a tuple for you I'm guessing) which you unpack into multiple values. This shouldn't cause any problems when using MP.

Comment: thanks for your comment - everything i write seems to come back around to a basic map:
```(a,b) = p.map(function(x, y, z), range(len(list1)))```
however, this is missing the actual list values.
When i drop it back into a for loop:
```for x in list1:
    (a,b) = p.map(function(x, y, z), range(len(list1)))```
i get errors for missing itterables

Comment: If you want to get more detailed help, you should probably provide more precise information in your question/comments, e.g. what is `p`? I would advise you to have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks i will do, realising i do not have enough info but didnt want to post the whole project!

Comment: @LiamJordan Too much is as bad as too little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is looks like an [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) problem, which could be solved with an approach similar to this:

```
import multiprocessing

n_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count() + 1
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n_proc)
proc_results = [
    pool.apply_async(func, func_args, func_kwargs)
    for func, func_args, func_kwargs in
    zip(funcs, funcs_args, funcs_kwargs)]
results = [
    proc_result.get() for proc_result in proc_results]
```

or an approach based on `multiprocessing`'s `map()` or `starmap()`.

---

## EDIT

In your case, the code:

```
for x in list1:
    a, b = function(x, y, z)
    if a is not None:
        list2.append(a)
    if b is not None:
        list3.append(b)
```

would become:

```
import multiprocessing

n_proc = multiprocessing.cpu_count() + 1
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n_proc)
proc_results = [pool.apply_async(function, (x, y, z), {}) for x in list1]
for proc_result in proc_results:
    a, b = proc_result.get()
    if a is not None:
        list2.append(a)
    if b is not None:
        list3.append(b)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, and your info, i have never heard the term before but you are correct, there are no dependencies. I am a beginner so it took me a few goes to implement your answer! However your edit made it much clearer thank you. It does seem to work! I receive the below error even though my code works, which i have never seen before, which i will start debugging. If you have any ideas i would appreciate it, and thank you for your response!
Reason: 'TypeError("can't pickle _thread.lock objects")'

Comment: It is hard to say what is happening, but it looks like the arguments of `function()` cannot be pickled correctly. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865430/multiprocessing-pool-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-thread-lock-attribu

Comment: Thanks for the assistance on this issue. I have marked what i believe to be the correct answer. I have a couple of issues which i believe to be unique to my class, that i cant easily provide working code for. The tool is a switch upgrade tool which can be found here: github.com/lsjordan/switch-upgrade-tool - it relies on network hardware unfortunately, but if anyone has any input to the multiprocessing branch i would be greatly appreciated! This is my first ever public project so please let me know if there are issues. @norok2