# How do you run a process that spawns multiple threads? How do you serialize a thread object?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm trying to create multiple processes in which each process takes in a group of threads that it will start. I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.lock' object
```

Here is a basic example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
import time
import threading
import multiprocessing


def threading_func(i):
    print(f'Starting Function {i}')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f'Ending Function {i}')


def process_func(threads):
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()


thread_list = [threading.Thread(target=threading_func, args=(i,)) for i in range(1, 9)]
processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=process_func, args=([thread],)) for thread in thread_list]
for process in processes:
    process.start()
for process in processes:
    process.join()
```

I am aware that the arguments passed into a `Process` instance must have the ability to be serialized. The real question, then, is how can I make a `Thread` object serialized?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [multiprocessing.Pool - PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'thread.lock'>: attribute lookup thread.lock failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865430/multiprocessing-pool-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-thread-lock-attribu)

Comment: Not quite :( they're getting a different error and using `Pool`. @Xiddoc

Comment: Booboo said, "There is no simple way of getting a Thread instance to be serializable." There's a reason for that. A thread represents an execution of your code. It's like having a party: It can only happen once. If you invite the same guests to the same place on a different day, you can have _another_ party, and you may do all the same things, and play the same tunes, etc., but it's _not_ the same party. It doesn't make any sense to try to copy a thread, and so there's no meaningful way to serialize (i.e., transmit a copy) of a `Thread` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way of getting a `Thread` instance to be serializable. An alternative would be to pass to each process the arguments required for it create the threads in its own address space. But this can be done rather painlessly by creating a class called `MyThread` that sort of behaves like the `Thread` class although it is meant to be used with the *target* argument since it does not have a `run` method:

```py
import time
import threading
import multiprocessing

class MyThread:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.thread = None

    def start(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.thread.start()

    def join(self):
        self.thread.join()


def threading_func(i):
    print(f'Starting Function {i}')
    time.sleep(1)
    print(f'Ending Function {i}')


def process_func(threads):
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_list = [MyThread(target=threading_func, args=(i,)) for i in range(1, 9)]
    processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=process_func, args=([thread],)) for thread in thread_list]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

**A version using a more generic `MyThread` class**

```py
import time
import threading
import multiprocessing

class MyThread:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.thread = None

    def start(self):
        self.thread = threading.Thread(*self.args, **self.kwargs) if 'target' in self.kwargs else threading.Thread(*self.args, **self.kwargs, target=self.run)
        self.thread.start()

    def join(self):
        self.thread.join()

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This method would need to be overridden if this class is not initialized
        with the `target` keyword and you wanted to perform something useful
        """
        pass

class T(MyThread):
    def run(self, i):
        print(f'Starting Function {i}')
        time.sleep(1)
        print(f'Ending Function {i}')


def process_func(threads):
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread_list = [T(args=(i,)) for i in range(1, 9)]
    processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=process_func, args=([thread],)) for thread in thread_list]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Each process is able to spawn multiple threads. Thank you

Comment: Your `MyThread` class would be better named, `MyTask` because it is _not_ a thread. It represents a unit of work that you want some thread to perform. (Note: keeping the idea of `Thread` separate from the `Task` (or maybe, multiple `Task`s that it performs) actually is a very _smart_ thing to do from a software engineering viewpoint.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow I see your point and it could be used in a more general context perhaps except I don't know what the additional `join` method would mean for a "general unit of work". For such a class I would just have a 'run' method, which when it returns is "joined.". But I called it `MyThread` because it does supports a subset of the `Thread` interface  -- well at least a slightly more generic version of the `MyClass` class does, which I have appended to the answer. Of course, there is probably not much need for this class except to solve the serializable problem posed by the OP. Take a look.