# python Pool with worker Processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am trying to use a worker Pool in python using Process objects.  Each worker (a Process) does some initialization (takes a non-trivial amount of time), gets passed a series of jobs (ideally using `map()`), and returns something.  No communication is necessary beyond that.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to use map() to use my worker's `compute()` function.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Process

class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Worker started'
        # do some initialization here
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

    def compute(self, data):
        print 'Computing things!'
        return data * data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This works fine
    worker = Worker()
    print worker.compute(3)

    # workers get initialized fine
    pool = Pool(processes = 4,
                initializer = Worker)
    data = range(10)
    # How to use my worker pool?
    result = pool.map(compute, data)
```

Is a job queue the way to go instead, or can I use `map()`?

Comment: All process objects are stateful.  You might want to remove that word from the title.  Also.  `compute` is a method of a Worker.  In the examples it's usually a completely stand-alone function. Why not write the compute function to simply include both initialization and processing?

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.  The initialization takes a long time, so I only want to do it once per worker process.

Comment: You must want to emphasize the "gets passed a series of jobs" part of the question.  Since that wasn't obvious.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I would suggest that you use a Queue for this.

```
class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        print('Worker started')
        # do some initialization here

        print('Computing things!')
        for data in iter(self.queue.get, None):
            # Use data
```

Now you can start a pile of these, all getting work from a single queue

```
request_queue = Queue()
for i in range(4):
    Worker(request_queue).start()
for data in the_real_source:
    request_queue.put(data)
# Sentinel objects to allow clean shutdown: 1 per worker.
for i in range(4):
    request_queue.put(None)
```

That kind of thing should allow you to amortize the expensive startup cost across multiple workers.

Comment: That's what I figured, thanks!  I ended up using a job queue (input) and result queue (output) to synchronize everything.

Comment: you example is awesome, i try right now how to input the sentinel objects when strg + c is pressed without an exepction

Comment: @S.Lott: Isn't it that Queue isn't pickle-able? and that's why you use [multiprocessing.Manager().Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217002/how-do-you-pass-a-queue-reference-to-a-function-managed-by-pool-map-async)?

Comment: It is really *much more customizable* than the default `multiprocessing.Pool()`!!!

Comment: This way will create 4 separate processes. If you want a pool of workers to run in a single process, use Pool https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

Answer (score 7):

`initializer` expects an arbitrary callable that does initilization e.g., it can set some globals, not a `Process` subclass; `map` accepts an arbitrary iterable:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import multiprocessing as mp

def init(val):
    print('do some initialization here')

def compute(data):
    print('Computing things!')
    return data * data

def produce_data():
    yield -100
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
    yield 100

if __name__=="__main__":
  p = mp.Pool(initializer=init, initargs=('arg',))
  print(p.map(compute, produce_data()))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since python 3.3 you can use starmap, also **for using multiple arguments AND getting back the results** in a very simplistic syntax:

```
import multiprocessing

nb_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

def caps(nb, letter):
    print('Exec nb:', nb)
    return letter.upper()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    multiprocessing.freeze_support() # for Windows, also requires to be in the statement: if __name__ == '__main__'

    input_data = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']
    input_order = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=nb_cores) as pool: # auto closing workers
        results = pool.starmap(caps, zip(input_order, input_data))

    print(results)
```