# How do i get multiple processess to update the same dictionary in python multiprocess

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a program which bottleneck is API calls, so I want to make the API calls to be done at the same time. In pseudocode, this is what I would like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

urls = ['www.example.com/item/1', 'www.example.com/item/2', 'www.example.com/item/3']

def get_stats(url, d):
    data = http.get(url)
    d[data['name']] = data['data']

manager = Manager()

d = manager.dict()

for url in urls:
    p = Process(target=get_stats, args=(url, d))
    p.start()
    p.join()

print d
```

The only thing is that these processes don't seem to be running in parallel.

Is it because I am placing the `join()` after starting the process?

What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: you don't need processes for this - just use threads.

Comment: may you please answer with a code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> these processes don't seem to be running in parallel

The `join()` inside your "starter loop" waits for each process to terminate before starting the next one.

Try something like this, instead:

```
procs = []
for url in urls:
    p = Process(target=get_stats, args=(url, d))
    p.start()
    procs.append(p)

for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

You might also want to have a look at the answer to
[Pool with worker Processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038711/python-pool-with-worker-processes#answer-9039979), as for your workload, using a [process `Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) seems like a good idea.

Comment: thank you, the last for loop there, wont that now also make each subsequent process wait for the next one in the loop

Comment: @BrandonSwallow The last loop makes the main process wait for all the child processes, one by one. The children still run in parallel before and during that.