# Python Multiprocessing and Queues

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a code snippet taken from another stackoverflow post
[Python Workers and Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038711/python-pool-with-worker-processes)

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from Queue import Queue

class Worker(Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.queue= queue

    def run(self):
        print 'Worker started'
        # do some initialization here

        print 'Computing things!'
        for data in iter( self.queue.get, None ):
            print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':       
    request_queue = Queue()
    for i in range(4):
        Worker( request_queue ).start()
    for data in range(100):
        request_queue.put( data )
    # Sentinel objects to allow clean shutdown: 1 per worker.
    for i in range(4):
        request_queue.put( None )
```

Why does this process hang and not process the queue contents?

Comment: Works for me!!, What's the error?

Comment: shouldn't it print out the numbers 0-99?  I do not get the numbers to print out it is hung at the line ---

    for data in iter( self.queue.get, None )  

Like it iterated on the Queue but since the new data arrives after the iteration it does not see the new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error.  I did not know there are two Queues.

changing

```
 from multiprocessing import Process
 from Queue import Queue
```

to

```
 from multiprocessing import Process,Queue
```

Now I have the expected behavior