# Python Threading and Multiprocessing in the same code causing pickling error

Tags: python, multithreading

While using Python3 on Windows 7 to process some large csv files I have run into a issue with the program not running fast enough.  The original working version of the code is similar to below, but the process calls are both threads.  Upon adding the `multiprocessing` library and transferring the `tdg.Thread` to the `mp.Process` as it shows below I receive this pickling error:

```
line 70, in <module>
    proc1.start()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_thread.lock'>: attribute lookup lock on _thread failed
```

Code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading as tdg
import queue as q

def my_p1func1(data, Q):
    #performs LDAP for data set 1
    print("p1f1:",data)


    Q.put(data)

def my_p1func2(data, Q):
    #performs LDAP for data set2
    print("p1f2:",data)

    Q.put(data)

def my_proc1(data, Q):

    f1_Q = q.Queue()
    f2_Q = q.Queue()

    f1 = tdg.Thread(target=myP1Func1, args = (data['1'], f1_Q))
    f2 = tdg.Thread(target=myP1Func2, args = (data['2'], f2_Q))

    f1.start()
    f2.start()

    f1.join()
    f2.join()

    f1_out=f1_Q.get()
    f2_out=f2_Q.get()

    Q.put({'f1':f1_out,'f2':f2_out})

def my_p2func1(data, Q):
    #perform gethostbyaddr() for data set 1
    print("p2f1:",data)

    Q.put(data)

def my_p2func2(data, Q):
    #perform gethostbyaddr() for data set 2
    print("p2f2:",data)

    Q.put(data)

def my_proc2(data, Q):

    f1_Q = q.Queue()
    f2_Q = q.Queue()

    f1 = tdg.Thread(target=myP2Func1, args = (data['1'], f1_Q))
    f2 = tdg.Thread(target=myP2Func2, args = (data['2'], f2_Q))

    f1.start()
    f2.start()

    f1.join()
    f2.join()

    f1_out=f1_Q.get()
    f2_out=f2_Q.get()

    Q.put({'f1':f1_out,'f2':f2_out})

dataIn = {'1': [1,2,3], '2': ['a','b','c']}
pq1 = q.Queue()
pq2 = q.Queue()

proc1 = mp.Process(target=my_proc1, args=(dataIn, pq1))
proc2 = mp.Process(target=my_proc2, args=(dataIn,pq2))

proc1.start()
proc2.start()

proc1.join()
proc2.join()

p1 = pq1.get()
p2 = pq2.get()

print(p1)
print(p2)
```

I though the issues was being caused by Locks I had around my print statements, but even after removing them it continues to throw the same pickling error.

I am in over my head with this and would appreciate any help understanding why it is attempting to pickle something not in use and how do I get this running so that it is more efficient?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865430/multiprocessing-pool-picklingerror-cant-pickle-type-thread-lock-attribu

Comment: It actually turned out to be [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217002, however fixing that in my real code led to a broken pipe error.  So now I am off to research how to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a regular `Queue.Queue` object with `multiprocessing`. You have to use a [`multiprocessing.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue). The standard `Queue.Queue` won't be shared between the processes, even if you were to make it picklable. It's an easy fix, though:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    dataIn = {'1': [1,2,3], '2': ['a','b','c']}
    pq1 = mp.Queue()
    pq2 = mp.Queue()

    proc1 = mp.Process(target=my_proc1, args=(dataIn, pq1))
    proc2 = mp.Process(target=my_proc2, args=(dataIn, pq2))

    proc1.start()
    proc2.start()

    proc1.join()
    proc2.join()

    p1 = pq1.get()
    p2 = pq2.get()
```

Comment: While this stopped the pickling error, there is no output from the `print` statements. Why would it not print if it moved into the processes appropriately?

Comment: @Olsonm76 Just noticed you're on Windows, which means you need the `if __name__ == "__main__":` guard. I added it into my answer. Not sure if that is the only issue remaining or not, though. I'll keep looking.

Comment: I added the guard, but no change.  I did however, discover that once this is run that I never return to idle state despite re-obtaining my cursor.

Comment: @Olsonm76 Are you running this from IDLE? If so, that's probably why you don't see output from the print statements. IDLE doesn't work properly with  `multiprocessing`. Try running your script directly from the CLI.