# Python multiprocessing Pool Queues communication

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement a pool of two processes that run in parallel and communicate through a queue.

The goal is to have a *writer* process that passes a message to a *reader* process by using a *queue*.

Each process is printing a feedback on the terminal in order to have a feedback.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import Queue

def writer(queue):
    pid = os.getpid()
    for i in range(1,4):
        msg = i
        print "### writer ", pid, " -> ", msg
        queue.put(msg)
        time.sleep(1)
        msg = 'Done'
    print '### '+msg
    queue.put(msg)

def reader(queue):
    pid = os.getpid()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    while True:
        print "--- reader ", pid, " -> ",
        msg = queue.get()
        print msg
        if msg == 'Done':
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Initialize the experiment PID: ", os.getpid()
    mp.freeze_support()

    queue = mp.Queue()

    pool = mp.Pool()
    pool.apply_async(writer, (queue)) 
    pool.apply_async(reader, (queue))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

The output I am expecting should be something like this:

```
Initialize the experiment PID: 2341
writer 2342 -> 1
reader 2343 -> 1
writer 2342 -> 2
reader 2343 -> 2
writer 2342 -> 3
reader 2343 -> 3
Done
```

However I only get the line:

```
Initialize the experiment PID: 2341
```

then the script quits.

What is the correct way to implement the interprocess communication of two processes in a pool that communicates through a queue?

Comment: Your `apply_async` is swallowing an exception, that you can't pass a `queue` around like that.  According to this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217002/how-do-you-pass-a-queue-reference-to-a-function-managed-by-pool-map-async), simply make the queue a global or use a [manager derived queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers).

Comment: Perfect, now it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I Used `mp.Manager().Queue()` as the queue because we couldn't directly pass `Queue`. Trying to directly use the `Queue` was causing exceptions but getting unhandled since we were using `apply_async`.

I updated your codes to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import time
import multiprocessing as mp
import Queue

def writer(queue):
    pid = os.getpid()
    for i in range(1,4):
        msg = i
        print "### writer ", pid, " -> ", msg
        queue.put(msg)
        time.sleep(1)
        msg = 'Done'
    print '### '+msg
    queue.put(msg)

def reader(queue):
    pid = os.getpid()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    while True:
        print "--- reader ", pid, " -> ",
        msg = queue.get()
        print msg
        if msg == 'Done':
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Initialize the experiment PID: ", os.getpid()
    manager = mp.Manager()

    queue = manager.Queue()

    pool = mp.Pool()
    pool.apply_async(writer, (queue,))
    pool.apply_async(reader, (queue,))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

And I got this output:

```
Initialize the experiment PID:  46182
### writer  46210  ->  1
--- reader  46211  ->  1
### writer  46210  ->  2
--- reader  46211  ->  2
### writer  46210  ->  3
--- reader  46211  ->  3
### Done
--- reader  46211  ->  Done
```

I believe this is what you expected.